# UserScript that tracks Views Since Last Visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, stackexchange, userscript

I *try* keep an eye on any questions or answers that I have posted here within the StackExchange network and I like to prioritize my updates and improvements based on ones that get frequent visits.

I previously used a paper sticky note attached to the side of my monitor with question titles and view counts scribbled on them but this was less than desirable.

I created a UserScript that adds a `track views` button into the question 
summary.

[image: track views]

Once activated it will display how many views that question has had since the last time you visited it.

[image: tracked views]

Visiting the Questions or Answers tab under the user profile will also display the recent views to all tracked posts.

[image: tracked views questions tab]

---

As usual, everything is working but I would like to get some pointers on how I can improve. I've taken pointers from my last two posts here and tried to run with them, hopefully my implementation is improving.

Note: *I didn't include all urls in the meta match tag intentionally, I didn't want to add too much clutter in this post*

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Question View Tracker
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/
// @author       enki
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*/*?tab=questions*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*/*?tab=answers*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*/*?tab=questions*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*/*?tab=answers*
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_deleteValue
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
"use strict";
$(function() {
    if(tracker.isOnPost()) {
        var postid = $("input[name='_id_']:first").val(),
            $qinfo = $("#qinfo"),
            $asked = $qinfo.find("tr td p:contains('asked')"),
            $active = $qinfo.find("tr td p:contains('active')"),
            $views = $qinfo.find("tr td p:contains('times')"),
            count = $views.text().replace(" times", "");

        //create table row for recent views
        var $recentviews = $('<tr/>').append(
            $('<td/>').append(
                $('<p/>', {
                    'class': 'label-key',
                    text: 'recent'
                })
            )).append(
            $('<td/>', {style: "padding-left: 10px;"}).append(
                $('<p/>', {
                    'class': 'label-key'
                }).append(
                    $('<b/>', {
                        id: 'recent',
                        text: '0 times',
                        style: "display: none;"
                    })
                ).append(
                    $('<a/>', {
                        id: 'track',
                        text: 'track views'
                    }).on('click', function(){
                        var $link = $(this),
                            $recent = $("#recent"),
                            state = $link.text();
                        if (state == "track views"){
                            tracker.track(postid, count);
                            $link.text("untrack");
                            $recent.html("0 times &mdash; ").show();
                        } else if (state == "untrack") {
                            tracker.untrack(postid);
                            $link.text("track views");
                            $recent.hide();
                        }
                    })
                )
            )
        );

        // rearrange question info to place active stat below the asked stat
        $active.closest("tr").insertAfter($asked.closest("tr"));

        // add recent views to question info after view count
        $recentviews.closest("tr").insertAfter($views.closest("tr"));

        // check if question views are being tracked
        if (tracker.isTracked(postid)) {
            console.log("tracker - isTracked");
            // get last count before we update it
            var lastcount = tracker.lastCount(postid);

            // update view count
            tracker.track(postid, count);

            // update recent views element and change tracking link text
            $("#recent").html((count - lastcount) + " times &mdash; ").show();
            $("#track").text("untrack");
        }

    } else if (tracker.isOnTab("questions")) {
        $(".question-summary").each(function () {
            var questionid = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];

            if(tracker.isTracked(questionid)){
                // view counts over 1k are placed inside a span tag title attribute otherwise view count is within .mini-counts div tag
                var questionViewCount = $(this).find(".views .mini-counts span").attr("title"),
                    questionLastcount = tracker.lastCount(questionid);

                // view count must be less than <1k
                if(questionViewCount == undefined){
                    questionViewCount = $(this).find(".views .mini-counts").text();
                } else { 
                    questionViewCount = parseInt(questionViewCount); // strip ' views' from number
                }

                $(this).find("h3").append($("<div/>", {"class": "started"})
                                          .append($("<span/>", {"class":"reputation-score", text: questionViewCount - questionLastcount })
                                                  .append($("<span/>", {text: " recent views",
                                                                        style: "font-weight: 100;"})
                                                         ))

                                         );
            }

        });
    } else if(tracker.isOnTab("answers")){
        $(".answer-hyperlink").each(function() {
            var $link = $(this),
                href = $link.attr("href"),
                answerid = href.split("/")[2];

            if(tracker.isTracked(answerid)){
                var answerLastCount = tracker.lastCount(answerid);

                // fetch current view count from url
                $.ajax({ url: href, 
                        dataType: 'html', 
                        success: function(response) { 
                            // get view count and add recent view count to answer summary
                            var answerViewCount = parseInt($(response).find("#qinfo tr td p:contains('times')").text());
                            $link.closest(".answer-summary").append($("<span/>", {text: answerViewCount - answerLastCount + " recent views — ",
                                                                                  style: "padding: 6px 5px 0 0; float: right;"}));
                        }});
            }
        });
    }
});

function tracker() {};
tracker.track = function(postid, count) {
    GM_setValue(this.trackerId(postid), count);
}
tracker.untrack = function(postid) {
    GM_deleteValue(this.trackerId(postid));
}
tracker.isTracked = function(postid) {
    //if result is undefined return false (not being tracked)
    return (GM_getValue(this.trackerId(postid)) === undefined ? false : true);
}
tracker.lastCount = function(postid) {
    return GM_getValue(this.trackerId(postid));
}
tracker.isOnPost = function() {
    return ($(location).attr('href').indexOf('/questions/') > -1 ? true : false);
}
tracker.isOnTab = function(tabName) {
    return ($(location).attr('href').indexOf("?tab=" + tabName ) > -1 ? true : false);
}
tracker.trackerId = function(postid){
    // post ids are not unique across stackexchange sites so we append the sitename to the postid and make it unique..
    var site = window.location.hostname.replace(".com", "").replace(".", "");
    return postid + site;
}
```